# Using Amazon SNS with Delphi FireMonkey

Tags: amazon-web-services, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I'm trying to create push notifications for my mobile application.
Is it possible integrate Delphi FireMonkey with Amazon SNS services?

Thanks.

*(Using Delphi 10 Seattle)*

Comment: I suggest looking here: http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/my-amazon-web-services-programming-with-delphi-coderagex-session

Comment: AWS SDK for Delphi supports Amazon SNS: https://github.com/landgraf-dev/aws-sdk-delphi

Answer (score 2):

The Amazon APIs are REST based. You can simply use the INDY component library or maybe even the Rest Client that shipped recently with Delphi. Also, Delphi has built in classes for talking to many of the AMAZON services like S3. You can use those as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Integrator from n/software makes it easy to access Amazon Web Services from Delphi

Easy-to-use components can be used to add, modify and delete objects stored on S3 or SimpleDB, add or remove messages from SQS, integrate with ASW e-commerce services, or control EC2 instances. As well as SNS

https://www.nsoftware.com/in/amazon/

Comment: In no way whatsoever, I was looking for this because I'm middle a project of integrating SNS with Delphi

Comment: OK, I've deleted my query.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is Yes.

Its possible to use Amazon Cloud API with Delphi. Extending Cloud API, Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) let you send notifications using different protocols including email, http and push notifications. *(TAmazonSNS Service)*

There are 3 provided classes to access Amazon Web Services with Cloud API:

- Simple Storage Service (S3)
- Simple Database Service (SimpleDB)
- Simple Queue Service (SQS)

Also you can check Paweł Głowacki's Amazon Web Services Delphi CodeRage X [demos from here](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/embt/events/CodeRageX/CloudAPI_CodeRageX_Final.zip).

Comment: It seems that Simple Database Service (SimpleDB) is replaced by DynamoDB

Comment: @A.Fornés DynamoDB is newest service. But [SimpleDB is still available.](https://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/)